# How to show storyboard instead of text

Tags: xcode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6kld.jpg)

Im a noob when it comes to this but, I wanted to show the storyboard file that I made instead of the "Hello world" when I launch the app. Pls Help..

Answer (score 0):

You created a SwiftUI project in your screenshot. That's why you have code instead of a storyboard file.

The fix is to choose Storyboard from the Interface menu when creating the project. Then choose File > Add Files to ProjectName to add your storyboard file to the project. Xcode defaults to using SwiftUI for new projects so you have to explicitly choose Storyboard to use storyboards for your app's user interface.

[image]

If you don't see the Interface menu in the second step of creating the project, make sure you didn't select a Multiplatform project. Multiplatform projects don't have the option to choose a storyboard for the user interface.